# How to get request when logging the response in Axis2

Tags: logging, apache-axis

When logging requests and responses in Axis2 I need to access the request message in out flow in logging module. I have created a custom logger to log the in and out messages. But, my requirement is to get the request message when logging the response message. Is there a way to access the request message when the logger is registered in out follow?